# Compound Select using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

What is equivalent of following code snippet in lambda expression?

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };

var pairs =
    from a in numbersA
    from b in numbersB
    where a < b
    select new { a, b };
```

Comment: Just fired up ILSpy to find out, but it didn't change it into methods. (Looks like i'll have to wait for @Jon Skeet!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a LINQ expression using **method syntax** (as opposed to **query syntax**):

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 }; 
int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 }; 

pairs = numbersA
  .SelectMany(_ => numbersB, (a, b) => new { a, b })
  .Where(x => x.a < x.b);
```

The original query is translated into this:

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 }; 
int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 }; 

pairs = numbersA
  .SelectMany(_ => numbersB, (a, b) => new { a, b })
  .Where(x => x.a < x.b)
  .Select(x => new { x.a, x.b });
```

However the last `Select` isn't required and can be removed.

Comment: +1, Is that actually what it's translated to, or is that just how you would do it?

Comment: @George Duckett: I have expanded my answer to answer your comment.

Comment: Thanks, out of interest, how did you find out the original translation?

Comment: I knew that having multiple `from` translates into `SelectMany` but I wasn't exactly sure about the last `Select` so I compated the generated IL and saw it was the same.